# MultiLabel Classification using Conditional Random Field

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, multilabel-classification, crf

Is it possible to use Conditional Random Field for MultiLabel Classification? I saw a python CRF implementation at https://pystruct.github.io/user_guide.html, but couldn't figure a way to do multilabel classification.

Comment: You may get better luck asking this question on either http://stats.stackexchange.com or http://datascience.stackexchange.com/. Be sure to check out their "How to Ask" pages first, to double check your question is on-topic there; http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and http://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The basic CRF doesn't support multilabel classification. However, some extensions have been explored, such as the Collective Multi-label (CML) and the
Collective Multi-label with Features (CMLF). From (1):

> A conditional random field (CRF) based model
>   is presented in [21] where two multi-label
>   graphical models has been proposed, both parameterizes
>   label co-occurances. The Collective
>   Multi-label (CML) classifier maintains feature
>   accounting for label co-occurances and the
>   Collective Multi-label with Features (CMLF)
>   maintains parameters that correspond to features
>   for each co-occuring label pair. Petterson
>   et. al. recently presented another interesting
>   generative modeling approach in a reverse manner,
>   predicting a set of instances given the labels [39].

---

References:

- (1) Sorower, Mohammad S. "A literature survey on algorithms for multi-label learning." Oregon State University, Corvallis (2010). http://people.oregonstate.edu/~sorowerm/pdf/Qual-Multilabel-Shahed-CompleteVersion.pdf ; https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=11211211207326445005&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22
- (21) N. Ghamrawi and A. Mccallum. Collective Multi-Label Classification. In Proceedings of
  the 3005 ACM Conference on Information and Knowledge Management (CIKM ’05), pages
  195–200, Bremen, Germany, 2005. http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a440081.pdf
- (39) James Petterson and Tiberio Caetano. Reverse multi-label learning. In J. Lafferty, C. K. I.
  Williams, R. Zemel, J. Shawe-Taylor, and A. Culotta, editors, Advances in Neural Information
  Processing Systems 23, pages 1903–1911. 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a modified CRF named [fuzzy CRF](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.03599.pdf) as shown below.

[image]

Its mathematics is quite simple as we can see from equation 2 in the paper:

[image]

We just sum all the energies of the paths in the numerator, and the denominator remains the same. For inference, we can apply Viterbi or beam search.